Django: psychopg2 unique violation error anyway to fix this
I was updating my django projects version from 2.1 to 2.2 and it looks like some errors occurred with my staging database (I am assuming from all the answers that look similar to my problem). I however am unsure on how to correct this without losing or corrupting the data any further. Attached are the console errors I am facing, anyway to solve these?
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [36;1mOperations to perform:[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [1m  Apply all migrations: [0madmin, adverts, apple_news, articles, auth, bookmarks, captcha, checkins, contacts, contenttypes, contests, custom_flatpages, events, favourites, features, flatpages, hipimagingtools, home, listings, notifications, patio_guide, photos, profiles, ratings, sessions, sites, slide_shows, streams, tastypie, team, todos, videos
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [36;1mRunning migrations:[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length...[32;1m OK[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions...Traceback (most recent call last):
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_permission_content_type_id_key"
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id, codename)=(114, add_djangouser) already exists.
[ubuntu@staging.internal. out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     utility.execute()
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [36;1mOperations to perform:[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [1m  Apply all migrations: [0madmin, adverts, apple_news, articles, auth, bookmarks, captcha, checkins, contacts, contenttypes, contests, custom_flatpages, events, favourites, features, flatpages, hipimagingtools, home, listings, notifications, patio_guide, photos, profiles, ratings, sessions, sites, slide_shows, streams, tastypie, team, todos, videos
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [36;1mRunning migrations:[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length...[32;1m OK[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions...Traceback (most recent call last):
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_permission_content_type_id_key"
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id, codename)=(114, add_djangouser) already exists.
[ubuntu@staging.internal. out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     utility.execute()
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [36;1mOperations to perform:[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [1m  Apply all migrations: [0madmin, adverts, apple_news, articles, auth, bookmarks, captcha, checkins, contacts, contenttypes, contests, custom_flatpages, events, favourites, features, flatpages, hipimagingtools, home, listings, notifications, patio_guide, photos, profiles, ratings, sessions, sites, slide_shows, streams, tastypie, team, todos, videos
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: [36;1mRunning migrations:[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length...[32;1m OK[0m
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions...Traceback (most recent call last):
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_permission_content_type_id_key"
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id, codename)=(114, add_djangouser) already exists.
[ubuntu@staging.internal. out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: 
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out: Traceback (most recent call last):
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     utility.execute()
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:   File "/project_name/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
[ubuntu@staging.internal.] out:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)

for added context this code was added to fix proxy permissions before and now when i update from 2.1 to 2.2 (when proxy permissions are fixed) the migration shoots an error
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
"""Add permissions for proxy model.
 
This is needed because of the bug https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154
in Django (as of 1.6, it's not fixed).
 
When a permission is created for a proxy model, it actually creates if for it's
base model app_label (eg: for "article" instead of "about", for the About proxy
model).
 
What we need, however, is that the permission be created for the proxy model
itself, in order to have the proper entries displayed in the admin.
 
"""
 
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import, division
 
from django.contrib.auth.management import _get_all_permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.apps import apps
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
 
 
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Fix permissions for proxy models."
 
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for model in apps.get_models():
            opts = model._meta
            ctype, created = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
                app_label=opts.app_label,
                model=opts.object_name.lower(),
                defaults={'name': smart_text(opts.verbose_name_raw)})
 
            for codename, name in _get_all_permissions(opts, ctype):
                p, created = Permission.objects.get_or_create(
                    codename=codename,
                    content_type=ctype,
                    defaults={'name': name})
                if created:
                    print p


It is telling you the problem duplicate key value violates unique constraint. You have a table with existing values that you are adding duplicate records to.

It looks like Django is trying to set up the permissions for your model. Do you have any model with a name like "djangouser" (The casing might differ)? Please share the models code (Specifically its Meta class should be important).
